# Map with Choroplethmapbox isn't showing in Dash

Tags: python, geojson, plotly-dash, choropleth

I am trying to build a map with `Choroplethmapbox` in Dash, but I cannot plot in that.

I test the geojson with another tool and in that tools, the map is drawn correctly, but not with `Choroplethmapbox`.

Any idea about what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

**GeoJson:**

https://gist.github.com/Tlaloc-Es/5c82834e5e4a9019a91123cb11f598c0

**Python Dash Code:**

```
import json
with open('mexico.geojson') as f:
    counties = json.load(f)
fig = go.Figure(go.Choroplethmapbox(
    geojson=counties,
    locations=df['COV_'],
    z=df['Enero'],
    colorscale="Viridis", zmin=0, zmax=df['Enero'].max(),
    marker_opacity=0.5, marker_line_width=0))

fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                  mapbox_zoom=3, mapbox_center = {"lat": 37.0902, "lon": -95.7129})
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem as well. I think in your case may be using this link might help: https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-county-choropleth/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add an id filed wit this code:

I used the code of this page: https://community.plot.ly/t/plot-a-shapefile-shp-in-a-choropleth-chart/27850

Comment: frustrating that the question is about DASH but most of the links are referencing plotly, these two things are drastically different in the way they render. I am having the same issue in DASH but my identical plotly code works well at producing an html vs a live application with DASH.

Answer (score 2):

looks like you are missing the **fig.show()** at the bottom and **import plotly.graph_objects as go** at the top. The code below will open a map, but data is needed for the choropleth values. You have df in your code example but you did not include a csv. If you want to us the df that is in your code, import pandas, and create a data frame called df from the csv. Here is a link that can help with that. [Pandas dataframes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

```
import json
import plotly.graph_objects as go


with open(r'{insert file path here}.geojson') as f:
    counties = json.load(f)
fig = go.Figure(go.Choroplethmapbox(
    geojson=counties,
    colorscale="Viridis", zmin=0, zmax=100,
    marker_opacity=0.5, marker_line_width=0))

fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                  mapbox_zoom=3, mapbox_center = {"lat": 37.0902, "lon": -95.7129})
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

Here is an example of using pandas with you json.Further explanation of the code below can be found [here](https://plot.ly/python/mapbox-county-choropleth/)

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
    counties = json.load(response)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/fips-unemp-16.csv",
                   dtype={"fips": str})

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.choropleth(df, geojson=counties, locations='fips', color='unemp',
                           color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
                           range_color=(0, 12),
                           scope="usa",
                           labels={'unemp':'unemployment rate'}
                          )
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

Comment: That is not the problem I am using dash, so I don't need call show function.

Comment: Are you using pandas to define your csv as a dataframe? If not, then where is df defined at?

Comment: Sorry but you are a bit lost, the problem is not with that, .show or with df that I load before, I think that maybe the problem is with the geojson format o info or something, because I could load another shp converted to json, but not all. Thanks for all.

Comment: Yeah I think we are misunderstanding each other here. I am not familiar with Dash so I was simply looking at possible errors in your code from a conventional python standpoint. Best of luck to you

Comment: Thanks, I tried anyway your tips on jupyter notebook with show but dosn't work.

Comment: Okay i gotcha. If you can add the data frame that you are loading in, id be happy to keep brainstorming. I understand if you can't due to sensitive data, but it will be difficult to troubleshoot without it since some of the Choroplethmapbox parameters are based on it.

Comment: I think that is because in the geojson i don't have the id field but I am not sure. the dataset is https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=FCGz&id=1oXjC8xHW4kBYE9aP9HhHNLAquKjHfTN2

Answer (score 1):

I had to solve a similar problem and this is my solution applied to your problem (although with `px.choropleth_mapbox` instead of graph_objects which I found confusing for choropleths).

- The data that you link does not (at least not at the time of writing) have the column 'Enero'.
- You never define a Dash-app (`app.layout = ...`), while you can probably serve without it and just have `fig.show()` as suggested, explicit beats implicit. Thus creating a layout section is better.
- If I understand how it works, if you use GeoPandas you **do not** have to generate an 'id' or anything like that as you suggest in your own answer.

Anyways, hopefully my solution can serve as a working start for you. I added radio buttons so that you can select what data column to use for color.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import plotly.express as px

import geopandas as gpd

print('Loading data...')
gdf = gpd.read_file('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Tlaloc-Es/5c82834e5e4a9019a91123cb11f598c0/raw/709ce9126861ef7a7c7cc4afd6216a6750d4bbe1/mexico.geojson')
gdf = gdf.to_crs(epsg=4326)

print('Done!')
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
                dcc.RadioItems(
                    id='radio-color_on',
                    options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['AREA','PERIMETER']],
                    value='AREA',
                    labelStyle={'display': 'inline-block'}
                ),
    ],style={'width': '40%', 'display': 'inline-block',}),

html.Div([], style={'width':'100%'}),

    html.Div([
                dcc.Graph(id="fig")
    ],style={'width': '100%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'padding': '0 10',},),
]) 

@app.callback(
    Output("fig", "figure"), 
    [Input("radio-color_on", "value")])
def draw_choropleth(color_on):
    fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(gdf, 
                            geojson=gdf.geometry, 
                            locations=gdf.index, 
                            color=color_on,
                            color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
                            #range_color=(0, 12),
                            mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                            zoom=4, 
                            center = {"lat":gdf.centroid.y.mean(), "lon":gdf.centroid.x.mean()},
                            opacity=0.5,
                            )
    fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0},
                        height=700,
                        )
    
    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Saving this code to a file "myapp.py" and running it in the terminal as `python myapp.py` starts the development served, firing up a web browser, navigating to the url that it uses (it writes it out in the terminal, usually 172.0.0.1:8050) gives you this:

[image]

I am running these versions, from the defaults anaconda channel.

- dash                      1.19.0
- dash-core-components      1.3.1
- dash-html-components      1.0.1
- dash-renderer             1.1.2
- flask                     1.1.2
- geopandas                 0.8.1

PS. I actually used the data to ask a question about dash choropleth mapbox selection behavior ([Selection behavior in plotly-dash Choropleth mapbox plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68284193/selection-behavior-in-plotly-dash-choropleth-mapbox-plot)). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problems. With the show method, it works fine, sometimes with the dash too (using only callbacks). The problem occurs due to the really old version of dash, installed via default channel of anaconda (only one version 1.4.1). After installation via conda-forge channel newer version (in my case 1.13.4) it works.

```
conda install -c conda-forge dash dash-core-components \
                 dash-html-components dash-renderer dash-table
```